# Return a list of names based on multiple critera

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

The formula below will generate a list of names based on 1 criteria `(Completed Training=1, Completed Training=2)`.  I am looking for a way to be able to add criteria to the formula so that I can use the formula to generate a list based on department in addition to their training.

The current formula is

`{=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($A$1:$C$8,SMALL(IF($C1:$C$8=1, ROW($B$1:$B$8)),ROW(1:1)),2)),"",INDEX($A$1:$C$8,SMALL(IF($C$1:$C$8=1,ROW($B$1::$B$8)),ROW(1:2)),2))}`

In the example image below I would like to see who in the ENG department (which included ENG, ET, Maint, Machine) would need trained.  The end result would be: Anthony, Robert, and Jack.  Are there any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

[image: screenshot of excel]

Comment: Are you really only working with a table this small, or do you have more data? The reason I ask is I use a VBA script with combo box drop downs to filter a large data set I have, but it may be overkill if you're only working with a few rows.

Comment: It isn't clear from your question whether you want only ENG, or all ENG-related departments, which is a subset of all of the departments shown).  If it's just ENG, a simple solution is to add a helper column where you concatenate the contents of cols A and C.  Then your search term would be ENG1 in the helper column.  If it's a collection of ENG-related departments, it gets more complicated.

Comment: I am actually working with a lot more data. I only do this match/combo twice a year as part of an internal audit of multiple systems to ensure things (and people) are not falling through the cracks. The example above is just a super simplified example. The original information is listed by work/ process area but my final audit reports are distributed by department. That is why I wanted to try to find a way to combine all of the process areas. There is no rush, I went a head and manually compared everything for my report due on Monday.  I am still interested in alternatives if you have time.

Comment: Please post your formula as text

Comment: Your comment doesn't clarify the central question needed to help you.

Comment: How can I take the current formula and have it show me the names of people based on their department?

Comment: Any reason you can't just use Excel's built-in filters? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-data-in-an-Excel-table-7d8e9739-2898-4bfe-9d0f-c6204e6e5c8a

Comment: That is how I currently perform the task.  It takes about a week because of all of the conditions, people, and locations of the data.  I was hoping to find a way to somewhat automate things.

Comment: Here's the confusion: you say ENG includes: ENG, ET, Maint, Machine as departments.  So it isn't clear whether you need to include any/all of those departments in the search or just ENG.

Comment: Each department has process areas within that department.  The data comes from various sources and one of this is based on process area.  Currently I manually filter, copy, paste, etc to create a report for each department manager.  If I can get the formula to work, I would be able to have a template for each department that shows all of the applicable sub department employees without showing them people that they are not responsible for.  Does that make more since?

Comment: @Crainiac,  you're explaining the "why" but not the "what".  So we're selecting or filtering employees to build an ENG-specific list.  In your example, would that list be limited to Randolph and Jack (the only two in ENG), or would that list also include Anthony, Jason, and Robert (because their departments are part of ENG)?  BTW, if you "address" comments with @, like I did here, that user will be alerted to your post.  Otherwise, you may need to wait for people to stumble across it.

Comment: @fixer1234, I apologize but I am now getting confused.  I modified my initial question.  Hopefully that will clarify what I am trying to accomplish.  I am aware that I can do this with pivot tables, filters, and copy/paste.  If it is possible, a formula would make things a lot faster.